# Getting Top 5 values and its color name

Tags: python-3.x, list, opencv, dictionary

I've 2 values namely colors and counts. The loop code in python generates all the unique color count in an image. What I want is to get only top 5 or say 'n' highest counts and its corresponding color value.

'''
# Jointly loop through colors and counts

```
for color, count in zip(colors, counts):

    print("COLOR: {}, COUNT: {}".format(color, count))
    col_list = []
    col_list.append(colors)
    # Create placeholder image and mark all pixels as white
    SINGLE_COLOR = (255 * np.ones(IMG.shape)).astype(np.uint8)  # Make sure casted to uint8.

    # Compute binary mask of pixel locations where color is, and set color in new image
    color_idx = np.all(IMG[..., :] == color, axis=-1)
    SINGLE_COLOR[color_idx, :] = color

    # Write file to output with color and counts specified
    path = 'test_output'

    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)

    cv.imwrite(path+'/'+"color={}_count={}.png".format(color, count), SINGLE_COLOR)
```

'''

Comment: i tried implementing that using dictionaries and lists but couldn't succeed.

Comment: I used this and I could succeed but don't know if this is the right approach

   z = np.sort(counts)
    r_z = z[::-1]
    new_z = r_z[:cc_countval] 

then using the conditional 'if' statement to perform the actions.
*cc_countval is a variable that can take n desired int value.